# HttpURLConnection post doesn't work

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to post an object to my API but it doesn't work.

My API method looks like this

```
[Route("Route is working but wanna keep this address hidden")]
[System.Web.Http.Acceptverbs("POST")]
[HttpPost]
public void Post(Comment comment)
{
db.Comments.Add(comment);
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

So I have my API and this method and then when I press a button in my android application I want it to post to this method but nothing is beeing posted.

My Code in my android application

```
public class ConnectionPost extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("Keeping this address hidden");



        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

        JSONObject comment = new JSONObject();
        comment.put("Name","Joe");

        OutputStreamWriter ap_osw= new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        ap_osw.write(comment.toString());
        ap_osw.flush();
        ap_osw.close();

            Log.d("test", ""  + comment.toString());

        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

When I click my button I call a method that contains this code.

```
 ConnectionPost send = new ConnectionPost();
 send.execute();
```

In LogCat I can see my created object but nothing is beeing posted, so wondering what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Sorry for bad naming on some things will fix it later.

Comment: Have you check your android manifest file if you added the proper user permission and also haved you tried testing your API/Server side?

Comment: I added internet permission in my android manifest file and I have tested my API to see so it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me, leading to the dreaded, "works on my machine."

1) Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in the manifest?

2) Handle the exception, it will help you debug.

3) Read/log the response from the server, it will help you debug.

```
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
reader.close();
in.close();
Log.d("test", result.toString());
```

A lot of times with connections it is the configuration that is failing NOT the code.  Your code is fine.

Comment: That's nice to hear that my code is working on your machine. If now my code is working on your machine but not on mine then you most have been doing something different, so what kind of configuration are we talking about?

Comment: In my answer I talk about adding the uses-permission tag, that is configuration.  Other times it is the wrong URL, and we do not log it so we do not see that the configuration of the URL is wrong causing the error.  That was what the 1, 2, 3 steps I listed above are for catching.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:) It was that in my object I have a DateTime field and I tried to set it as null when posting, but ofcourse it doesn't work. Changed it to DateTime.Now.

Comment: Probably would have caught that a lot sooner, if you had followed my advise and handled the exception.

Comment: Yeah I guess, but it was not only that. I also needed to add in my code a check to see if my API method returned responsecode 200 and if that is the case then it starts to post. But thanks for your help:)